# algorithm to assign points to winning users

Tags: algorithms

I have a set of users who have won a game

```
('jim', 12), ('james', 54), ('john', 76), ('dave', 22), ('garry', 34), ('stuart', 16)
```

I want to award them a share of points based on their position in the game on a sliding scale. The 'global pot' is $100 and I would like the winner to get the most with other users getting less based on a sliding scale to their position.

Would anyone know of a 'scoring' algorithm to do this...? Similar to ones used in poker but with a fixed pot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily use their fraction of the total points as the fraction of the pot to win. I.e., divide each score by the total of all the scores then multiply that by $100.